# Controls not loading when multithreading a form

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, forms

I have a `C#` `WinForms` application. When the main form loads, two other forms are loaded and hidden as I need them to run in the background. I keep 2 global variables pointing to them in order to be able to access them. I want to load them on a separate thread to reduce the loading time. For this, I have the following code in the main form's constructor:

```
if (!IsHandleCreated)
{
    CreateHandle();
}

//Start the license manager using a separate thread.
new Thread(delegate()
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        GlobalVariables.licenseManagerWindow = new LicenseManager();
        GlobalVariables.licenseManagerWindow.Show();
    }));
    bt_Licenses.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        bt_Licenses.Enabled = true;
    }));
}).Start();

//Start the employee app manager using a separate thread.
new Thread(delegate()
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        GlobalVariables.employeeAppManagerWindow = new ManageEmployeeApp();
        GlobalVariables.employeeAppManagerWindow.Show();
    }));
    bt_Employees.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        bt_EmployeeApp.Enabled = true;
    }));
}).Start();
```

The problem is that instead of showing the main form and updating the buttons after each form is loaded, the main form looks like this until both of the other forms are loaded:

[image]

As you can see, the controls don't load and they show transparently. Eventually they all load fine when the 2 forms load. If I comment out the code above, the main form loads perfectly fine. **I obviously don't want the user to see this skeleton while the forms load, but to see the controls. What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: You are creating threads from the UI thread (constructor of Form), which only schedule work back on the UI thread (using BeginInvoke on the form). That's pretty pointless.

Comment: Fair enough. What would be the correct way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure what your original problem is when you don't use threads.

Comment: If I don't use threads, my main form needs to wait for these 2 other forms to load. They are doing quite a bit of network communication so it takes a lot of time. I want to load them on separate threads so that my main form loads faster.

Comment: Also, I want to store a pointer to the 2 forms, which should be accessible from the UI thread, hence the reason for using the invokes.

Comment: Then don't use IO operations in the constructor. E.g. show form, use a task for the IO with a continuation once the IO completes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using background workers instead of threads. use the report progress / runworkercomplete events to write the results to your form. This prevents your UI waiting with the draw until the threads are completed and makes it that you don't have to manually handle the invokes of controls.

documentation and examples can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the two hidden forms in the main form's constructor, do it in the main form's "Load" event handler.

Windows forces you to load the hidden forms through the main thread (that's what BeginInvoke does), but you can minimize the impact to the main thread by having the hidden forms kick off the long-running network communication on a background thread from the hidden forms' "Load" event.

Comment: If you comment out the employee and license forms, does the main form's controls show properly?  If many classes are being loaded and many methods are being called for the first time, then you might be seeing a delay caused by the JITter.  Try using a Forms Timer to delay the loading of the employee and license forms by a 100 ms.  Kick off the Forms timer in the Load event handler of the main window.